# Bootstrap datepicker dynamically update multiple rows

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

I have table which contains multiple rows from database, within that table we have column for date which selects the date today for only one row. Since we have multiple rows i need to update the datepicker to all the rows.

I have tried for adding it to one row.

```
<script>
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
                format:'MM-dd-yyyy',
            }).datepicker("setDate",'now');
</script>

<td>
                                        <input type="text" name="DOD" 
style="width: 9.5em" id="datePicker">
                                </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple datepickers among multiple rows, you can't assign them with the same id `datePicker`. You need to use `class`:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="date-picker" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="date-picker" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="date-picker" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
<script>
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
        format:'MM-dd-yyyy',
    }).datepicker("setDate",'now');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the Suggestion. Since my table is dynamic from database, i do not want to assign values to be adding 3 or more times to the table. I need to loop them to each row as far as row keeps adding.

Comment: @Rocket: that's what I meant. Since you want to assign values to multiple rows, ID won't work! You have to use `class`. The 3 rows in the code sample are just.... samples.... You can definitely loop for the data to build the table dynamically.